# How to use component's insideHTML in the component template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I'm trying to learn about components. I have a component like this:

```
app.component('modal', {
    templateUrl: 'components/modal.html',
    bindings: {
        show: '<',
        title: '@',
    },
    controller: function () {}
});
```

This is how I use it:

```
<modal show="true" title="Create Campaign">Testing.</modal>
```

The component's content is: Testing.

And the template:

```
<div class="modal" ng-show="{{ $ctrl.show }}">
    <div class="modal__body">
        <div class="modal__header">
            {{ $ctrl.title }}
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-close modal__close" data-action="close"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="modal__content"></div>

        <div class="modal__footer">
            <button class="button button--default button--ghost" data-action="close">Cancel</button>
            <button ng-disabled="!modal.createCampaign.name" class="button button--primary button--wide pull-right"
                type="submit">Create Campaign</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How I put the component's innerHTML (Testing.) to the inside of .modal__content div?

Maybe ıt can be something like:

```
<div class="modal__content">{{ $ctrl.body }}</div>
```

Comment: did you try something like <div class="modal__content" [innerHtml]="YOUR HTML"></div> ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `transclude` option:

```
app.component('modal', {
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: 'components/modal.html',
    bindings: {
        show: '<',
        title: '@',
    },
    controller: function () {}
});
```

In html add `ng-transclude` where you want the content to be added:

```
<div class="modal__content" ng-transclude></div>
```

Read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component